# What solution to update the app without the base file?

Tags: android, google-play-console

A month ago I deleted the .jks file thinking it was a duplicate.
I had a file of the same name in my backups, unfortunately I deleted the wrong file and the file I have is not identical to the base signature

I lost the jks keystore file for publishing my app on google play console.

Comment: Eventually this post may help you https://medium.com/@farukcankaya/recover-your-lost-android-keystore-file-633c853bd11f

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to contact the support service. from Google.
You are requesting a reinitialization of the signing key. He will contact you directly by gmail.

I tested and they helped me quickly